# updating excel using python

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt

I have a workbook with multiple sheets in it. I am trying to read one sheet data and match to column fields in other sheet to see if they match update some column for that sheet. This is what I was trying. But as I understand XLRD can't be used to write. Can anyone point me to python library or module which can do both read and write at sam time:

```
`#!/usr/bin/python
import xlrd, xlwt
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('nagios.xlsx')
workbook1 = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet1 = workbook.sheet_by_name('contacts_users')
worksheet2 = workbook.sheet_by_name('contact_group_nagios')
    for row in range(1, worksheet2.nrows):
        print "value: ", worksheet2.cell(row,0).value
        print "value: ", worksheet2.cell(row,1).value
        s = worksheet2.cell(row,1).value
        grp_name = worksheet2.cell(row,0).value
        members = s.split(",")
            for member in members:
                for row1 in range(1, worksheet1.nrows):
                    if member == worksheet1.cell(row1,0).value:
                        s1 = worksheet1.cell(row1,3).value
                        s1 += grp_name
                        worksheet1.append(row1,3, s1)`
```

Comment: xl**r**t is for reading spreedsheets and xl**w**t is for writing them, you want to be using [`xlwt.Workbook.save`](http://xlwt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#xlwt.Workbook.Workbook.save) to save the workbook after making it.

Comment: example? Can we do read same workbook and save it via xlwt.

Comment: to save `workbook1` you would just need to do `workbook1.save("FILE_NAME")`

Comment: My question is not clear I guess. I want to edit same workbook in place. Want to read it and if some conditions match then edit it.

Comment: then use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/) you can [read an existing file](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) then [save it](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/usage.html#write-a-workbook-from-xltx-as-xlsx) either with the same name (overriding the previous version) or as a copy.  http://www.python-excel.org has it at the very top with the description "The recommended package for reading and writing Excel 2010 files (ie: .xlsx)"